# Get a whole div with a Jquery get Request. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

On my django  app I display a list of the user's facebook friend, using django-facebook.
The friends are sorted depending on there "activity" (if they are active or not).

I would like to refresh this list on my page without refreshing the whole page.

Here is my view:

```
class fb_friend(request)
    if request.user.userprofile.facebook_id:
        # Get Friends 

        profile = request.user.get_profile()
        idle_friends = profile.get_idle_facebook_friends()
        active_friends = profile.get_active_facebook_friends()
        offline_friends = profile.get_inactive_facebook_friends()
        friend_groups = (active_friends, idle_friends,  offline_friends)
```

In my template:

```
     <div>
    {% for group in friend_groups %}
     {% for friend in group %}
    <p>{{ friend.name }} ({{ friend.online_presence }})</p>
     {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

My idea would be to put the content of my view in an other view, and then use a JQuery request with a setInterval. 
But the problem is that I only know how to get one element of a page with a JQuery request.

So my question is how can I get the whole div with a JQuery get request and display it in my template?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is getting a div different from getting an "element" (whatever that is)?

Comment: Normally, to get an element I use: $.get('/mysite/get_friend/', {'element_to_get':element_to_get}, function(data) {
        $('.name_to_render_it').html(data);
        });                    So can I use the name of the div instead of only the name 'element_to_get'?